# Importing data into iOS app, now that iCloud replaced iTunes

Tags: ios, itunes, file-sharing, icloud

Until now it was possible to import data into an iPhone app using iTunes file sharing. The data (e.g. a pdf, doc or custom file format would then show up in /Documents directory and could be used by the app.

Now that Apple introduced iCloud and changed it's iOS Data Storage Guidelines (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html) does not seem to allow to save a document from the PC/Mac to iOS any longer:

> Only documents and other data that is user-generated, or that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application, should be stored in the /Documents directory and will be automatically backed up by iCloud.

**And I actually got rejected on this by Apple yesterday:**

> We found that your app does not follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines. 
>   Specifically, your application does not contain user-generated content or content that cannot otherwise be recreated by your application.

So here are my questions:

1. Does anybody know what Apple's policy will be in regards to this? If they don't want to use iTunes Filesharing for file imports they should disable it in iTunes...
2. What other ways would you suggest to import data into the app? I haven't figured out, how i could import data into my apps /Documents directory using iCloud from a Mac or PC

Comment: Have you tried to seek further info from the review team?

Comment: Yes, on all channels and still waiting for answers. They usually try to forward you to the technical support the app review team respectively so it's hard to get a real answer out of them.

Comment: I think your best bet at the moment would be to speak with them about both why it was rejected and how to fix it so you can still do what you want

Comment: The review team told me to contact technical support (though it's really a policy decision, nothing technical (yet)). Just waiting for the technical support team to tell me to contact the review team...

Comment: I complained in the resolution center and now I'm in review again. Maybe it's not that big of a thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTunes file sharing is still available post iCloud. I've just had an app approved that uses it.

I think the issue here is iCloud backup.  You need to mark files in the documents directory that can be re-created, so they are not backed up to iCloud.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

Comment: Thanks - yes that's what i figured out. It was a misunderstanding from Apple's side and the original application was approved after some complains :) --- I still think they need a more consisten scheme, maybe not automatically backup the files to the cloud that have been added by iTunes file sharing...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, false alarm...

It was a misunderstanding from Apple's side and the original application was approved after some complains :) --- I still think they need a more consisten scheme, maybe not automatically backup the files to the cloud that have been added by iTunes file sharing...

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem (minus the rejection, though, thanks to this post and others): PDF documents (in my case) are supposed to be copied to the app via iTunes (just like the Adobe Reader). They are obviously not user generated, so this conflicts with the iOS Data Storage Guidelines.

So, in the end, you got your original app accepted without marking files shared via iTunes as "do not back up"? You told them that the files in the Documents directory are put there by the user via iTunes and they were ok with it then?

I would mark files as "do not backup" but I don't think that is possible with shared files, because when shared, files are probably not marked as such, and I cannot assume that my app will notice the existence of new shared files. I can watch the Documents directory but that does not work if the app is not running...

It would be great if Apple fixed this. Not backing up shared files by default would be a good idea, because per definition, these files are not created by the user/app. Or they may decide to put shared files into some directory other than the Documents directory (Documents/Shared or something?) and exclude this from backup.